# Enabling "SR-IOV" & "Toggle passthrough" together for NVIDIA GPU on Ubuntu 22.04 VM

Tags: nvidia

We have created 2 VMs (Ubuntu 22.04) on Dell Server (PowerEdge R740xd) with NVIDIA A 100 GPU attached to each of VMs, we are unable to enable SR-IOV" & "Toggle passthrough" together for VMs.
Any help on this is appreciated.